# Batch Return Key Problems

Tags: batch-file

I type something like this (just an example)

```
    @echo off
    echo Blah Blah Blah
    echo Hello Joey
```

But if I were to run it, I get this

```
    Blah Blah Blah

    Hello Joey
```

Where did the extra space come from and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code with some.bat and got the below output.

```
    Blah Blah Blah
Hello Joey
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Try to create a new batch file with the below code

```
@echo off
echo Blah Blah Blah
echo Hello Joey
```

and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That was just an example. Would you like the actual code I'm having a problem with? I can give it to you and then you'll see what problem I'm having.

Comment: Just upgraded my OS. Not having this problem anymore.